# Scala: check and return field value from object in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-collections

> I have global variable option object is student

```
def getName(id: Int) : Option[Student] = {
if (student.isDefined){
  student.get.name
} else {
  ""
}
```

}
How to clean code here? Please help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a variable of type Option[Student]

```
case class Student(name:String)

val student:Option[Student] = Option(Student("a name"))
```

you can clean your code using map and getOrElse

```
student.map(_.name).getOrElse("")
```

map transforms your Option[Student] in a Option[String], which is a Some("name") or None.

then you can use getOrElse in order to get the value or an alternative value in case of None.

Be careful, it is a bad practice use "isDefined" and "get" methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`fold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Option.html#fold[B](ifEmpty:=%3EB)(f:A=%3EB):B) here:

```
student.fold(""){ _.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing if `id` is unused parameter so if you are not going to use it then remove it.

Make use of case classes.

`case class Student(name: String)`

`val student = Option(new Student("ABC"))`

`def getName() => if (student == None) StringUtils.Empty else student.name`